# How to Get LAST_INSERT_ID() in Node.js Using Promise Pool and Async

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await, promise, pool

I need to get the ID of the last record I entered in a MySQL DB. However, I am using Pooling, and the command that is supposed to get the ID seems to be on a different connection because it always responds with '0'.

Intialization:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dbConfig = require('../config/db.config.js');

var link = dbConfig.getConnection('central_development'); // <---- CHANGE TO PRODUCTION
```

Here is my `INSERT`:

```
function getCommandQueue(schemaName, pid, deviceId, setpoint) {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        var getCommeandQueueResponse;
        link.database = schemaName;

        const pool = mysql.createPool(link);
        const promisePool = pool.promise();

        try {

            getCommandQueueResponse = await promisePool.query('INSERT INTO CommandQueue (TargetID, PropertyID, Command, CommandOrigin, Disposition) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [deviceId, pid, 'USP', 'Central', 'Active']);

        } catch(error) {

            console.log(error);
            reject(error);

        } finally {

            resolve(getCommandQueueResponse);

        }
    })
}
```

And here is my `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
function getLastCommandQueueId(schemaName) {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, rejects) => {

        var getLastCommandQueueIdResponse;
        link.database = schemaName;

        const pool = mysql.createPool(link);
        const promisePool = pool.promise();

        try {

            getLastCommandQueueIdResponse = await promisePool.query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LAST_INSERT_ID');

        } catch(error) {

            console.log(error);
            reject(error);

        } finally {

            resolve(getLastCommandQueueIdResponse);

        }
    })
}
```

These two commands work fine, but they do not yield the desired result due to the pool using different connections.

I wrote the following query to resolve the issue

```
function getCommandQueue(schemaName, pid, deviceId, setpoint) {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        var getCommandQueueResponse;
        link.database = schemaName;

        const pool = mysql.createPool(link);
        const promisePool = pool.promise;

        connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });

        try {

            getCommandQueueResponse = await connection.query('INSERT INTO CommandQueue (TargetID, PropertyID, Command, CommandOrigin, Disposition) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [deviceId, pid, 'USP', 'Central', 'Active']);

        } catch (error) {

            reject(error);

        } finally {

            resolve (getCommandQueueResponse);
        }
    })
}
```

However, this code is failing due to: "connection not defined".

```
connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Can some please help me fix this?

Comment: Look at [docs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) again, `pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {` and
`connection` is only defined the `getConnection` which is where the queries should be, both of them, on the same connection.